# Leetcode problem 9. Palindrome Number (Python3). Why is my code failing?

Tags: python, palindrome

Here is the code:

```py
class Solution:
    def isPalindrome(self, x: int) -> bool:
        if str(x) == reversed(str(x)):
            return True
        else: 
            return False
```

The testcase where `x = 121` fails - it return False as output. But it seems to me that 121 must be equal to 121 reversed.
What is wrong?

Comment: Because `reversed` returns a `reversed` object(It does not evaluate immediately)

Comment: Also you don't need `if ... return True else return False` just do `return str(x) == ...` the result of an equality comparison is already a boolean.

Comment: You can use `str(x) == str(x)[::-1]` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This real issue is that `reversed()` returns an iterator.

```
print(reversed(str(5)))
<reversed at 0x22c166a78e0>
```

So, you are comparing a string with an iterator thats why you are getting False.

```
str(5)==reversed(str(5))
#False
```

This is the correct syntax:

```
str(5)==''.join(reversed(str(5)))
#True
```

Link to document : [reversed()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, a working solution would be:

```
class Solution:
    def isPalindrome(self, x: int) -> bool:
        return str(x) == str(x)[::-1]
```